# mongoimport hangs when running from within firewall

Tags: mongodb, port, firewall, netstat, mongoimport

I am trying to import data to my mongodb sevrer that is hosted on the cloud.

I run the following command from a linux server that is inside a corporate firewall:

`mongoimport --host myhost:10081 --db mydb -u myusr -p mypass --collection imptest --file test.dat  --drop --stopOnError`

The import starts running, connects to the remote mongod successfully, creates one record of data (checked my db) and then simply hangs forever with no error message.

I am quite sure that this happens due to some firewall settings which block communications back from the mongo server - when I do the same thing from outside the firewall it works perfectly.
Can I make mongoimport work with more optimistic WriteConcern, and not wait for acks? Or better yet, how can I find out which port being blocked is causing me the trouble?

Comment: You may want to run mongoimport with `-vvv` to make the process verbose, so you can see any errors or warnings.

Comment: @lobster1234 - tried that. It showed the doc it was about to insert but didn't show any error or warning.

Comment: Did you consult with MongoDB [firewall configuration guide](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security/#security-firewalls) ?

Comment: Did you tail the mongod logs on myhost:10081?

Comment: @Adil - I don't have access to the mongo server (it's on a cloud provider)

Answer (score 1):

I assume there are some ports which are most certainly open, like 22 for SSH. You could try setting up an SSH tunnel from within your firewall to the cloud based server. Then you need to forward connections on the mongoDB ports through the SSH tunnel.

Comment: I haven't done it personally, but these guys seem to have been successful: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongomapper/gKEbBs8fdxE